# Copy data into buffer to print at stdout

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, stdout, kernel-module

I am writing a linux kernel module that creates a block device which lists the process list.

I am able to display the list in the kernel log file but now I am trying to display the output to stdout. My aim is to create a big string in dev_open() that contains all the processes and then copy that string to the buffer which goes to the dev_read() function.

However, I am trying the following code but I get a message to stdout saying "Killed".

What does this mean ? How can I solve this.

Code ::

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include<linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

static int dev_open(struct inode *, struct file *);
static int dev_rls(struct inode *, struct file *);
static ssize_t dev_read(struct file *, char *, size_t, loff_t *);

int len,temp;
char msg[1000];
int tem;
static struct file_operations fops =
{
    .read = dev_read,
    .open = dev_open,
    .release = dev_rls,
};

int init_module(void)
{
    int t = register_chrdev(81,"tempo",&fops);

    if(t<0) printk(KERN_ALERT "Device failed to register!");
    else printk(KERN_ALERT "Registered device...\n");
    return t;
}

static int dev_open(struct inode *inod, struct file *fil)
{
    struct task_struct *task;   
    for_each_process(task)
    {
        printk("%s [%d]\n",task->comm, task->pid);
        strcat(&msg[0],task->comm);
        len=strlen(msg);
        temp=len;
        tem++;
    }
        printk("%s [%d]\n",task->comm , task->pid);

   return 0;
 }

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    unregister_chrdev(81,"tempo");
}

static ssize_t dev_read(struct file *filp,char *buf,size_t count,loff_t *offp)
{
    printk("Hi\n");
     if(count>temp)
   {
    count=temp;
   }
    temp=temp-count;
    copy_to_user(buf,msg, count);
    if(count==0)
       temp=len;

   return count;

   //return 0;
} 


static int dev_rls(struct inode *inod, struct file *fil)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT"Done with device\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's entirely possible that you're writing beyond the end of msg, since it's only 1000 bytes long and you have no limitation on the length. Are you getting a kernel stack trace in dmesg/syslog (or on the console)?

Comment: Also, your logic in dev_read doesn't really make sense to me. Probably you're intending to copy out up to count bytes (but no more than are available in msg), but I don't think that's what it actually does. Work through an example where there are, say, 800 bytes in msg, but the user does a read of 5 bytes, then another 5 and so forth. Watch what happens to your state variables.